# Как сделать анимацию превращения круга в квадрат?

Tags: java, android, анимация

Т.е чтобы края стали не круглыми, а острыми под 90 гр.

Comment: На чем отрисовываются фигуры?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Создаем в разметке квадратный `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    />
```

Его фон `rectangle.xml` лежит в папке `drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
</shape>
```

Здесь важно, чтобы радиус углов равнялся половине ширины `ImageView`. Тогда получится круг.

Далее в активити по нажатию на кнопку запускаем анимацию, постепенно уменьшающую радиус углов прямоугольника (от 100 до 0):

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
            shape.setColor(Color.RED);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100, 0);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    shape.setCornerRadius((int)animation.getAnimatedValue());
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(shape);
                }
            });
            anim.setDuration(5000);
            anim.start();
        }
    });
```

Работает на API, начиная с 11.